# How to add a custom LoginModule to Karaf Jaas security framework?

Tags: osgi, jaas, karaf

I'd like to add a custom LoginModule to Karaf Jaas framework, and create a new realm that will use it.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have my own solution as follows, implemented using Declarative Services.

First of all, create a new `LoginModule` implementation extending `org.apache.karaf.jaas.modules.AbstractKarafLoginModule`.

```java
public class CustomLoginModule extends AbstractKarafLoginModule
{
    public void initialize(Subject subject, CallbackHandler callbackHandler, 
        Map<String, ?> sharedState, Map<String, ?> options)
    {
        super.initialize(subject, callbackHandler, options);
        // Use the `options` parameter for extra information that will be used 
        // inside the module; this is passed from the JaasRealm service
    }

    public boolean login() throws LoginException
    {
        // prepare callback objects and get the authentication information

        Callback[] callbacks = new Callback[2];
        callbacks[0] = new NameCallback("Username: ");
        callbacks[1] = new PasswordCallback("Password: ", false);

        try {
            callbackHandler.handle(callbacks);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            throw new LoginException(e.getMessage());
        }

        user = ((NameCallback) callbacks[0]).getName();

        char[] tmpPassword = ((PasswordCallback) callbacks[1]).getPassword();
        if (tmpPassword == null)
            tmpPassword = new char[0];
        String password = new String(tmpPassword);

        // Do the custom authentication and throw `LoginException` if the user 
        // is not valid. Get the roles and groups that the user is assigned to.

        // .......

        // Add roles and groups along with the user information to the `principals`

        principals = new HashSet<>();
        principals.add(new UserPrincipal(user));

        for (String role : roles)
            principals.add(new RolePrincipal(role));
        for (String group: groups)
            principals.add(new GroupPrincipal(group));

        return true;
    }

    public boolean abort() throws LoginException
    {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean logout() throws LoginException
    {
        subject.getPrincipals().removeAll(principals);
        principals.clear();
        return true;
    }
}
```

Second; in order to use this class as the LoginModule of a new realm, we have to register a new `org.apache.karaf.jaas.config.JaasRealm` service and set our own login module. We will put this file in the same bundle with the `CustomLoginModule`.

```java
@Component(immediate = true)
public class CustomJaasRealmService implements JaasRealm
{
    public static final String REALM_NAME = "customRealm";

    private AppConfigurationEntry[] configEntries;

    @Activate
    public void activate(BundleContext bc)
    {
        // create the configuration entry field using ProxyLoginModule class

        Map<String, Object> options = new HashMap<>();
        configEntries = new AppConfigurationEntry[1];
        configEntries[0] = new AppConfigurationEntry(ProxyLoginModule.class.getName(),
            LoginModuleControlFlag.SUFFICIENT, options);

        // actual LoginModule class name will be passed using the options object

        options.put(ProxyLoginModule.PROPERTY_MODULE, CustomLoginModule.class.getName());

        // put bundle id of the LoginModule and bundlecontext of it 
        // (in this case, it is the same bundle)
        // This is a neat trick to adapt to OSGI classloader

        long bundleId = bc.getBundle().getBundleId();
        options.put(ProxyLoginModule.PROPERTY_BUNDLE, String.valueOf(bundleId));
        options.put(BundleContext.class.getName(), bc);

        // add extra options if needed; for example, karaf encryption
        // ....
    }

    @Override
    public AppConfigurationEntry[] getEntries()
    {
        return configEntries;
    }

    // return the name and the rank of the realm

    @Override
    public String getName()
    {
        return REALM_NAME;
    }

    @Override
    public int getRank()
    {
        return 0;
    }   
}
```